# Amplify CLI - Angular + Ionic - MFA - AdminQueries API : XMLHttpRequest.handleError [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror]

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli

So, I am using Amplify with ionic + angular and have followed the following link and sublinks there,

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/tutorials/building-ionic-4-apps/

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#administrative-actions

> Now, what I want to create is an Admin Panel in my application by
>   which I can create users with MFA enabled for login process (just as
>   it is done via the aws-cognito-console). Therefore, in my form I have
>   provided the email and phone_number as mandatory input fields and for
>   the password I am planning to create an auto-generated one using
>   javascript.

As I could understand from the docs, this is achievable via AdminQueries API and while initializing my project with `amplify cli` , I did the required configuration. As a result, I did get the boilerplate code ready in the amplify backend folder as displayed in the screen below,

[image: Check the highlighted yellow area]

Unfortunately, the boilerplate code didn't have an implementation of AdminCreateUser Method i.e.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property

therefore, I have myself created this method in the `cognitoActions.js` and the route for the same has been implemented in `app.js`, did some **CORS** settings and finally did an `amplify push`

But when I tried to access this api method from the amplify-angular methods, it gives me the following error (I have pasted the error below the screenshot)

[image]

This is what all I have in my request, response headers,

[image]
[image]

`{"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network Error\n    at createError (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:263903:15)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror] (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:263394:14)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:4541:39)\n    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3741:31)\n    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:70625:33)\n    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3740:60)\n    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3518:47)\n    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3815:34)\n    at invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:4953:14)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:4979:17)","config":{"url":"https://4wdmydkl7e.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test/addUser","method":"post","data":"{\"user\":{\"firstname\":\"Prateek\",\"lastname\":\"k\",\"email\":\"opensource.prateek@gmail.com\",\"phoneNumber\":\"+918700416661\",\"specialization\":\"instrumentation\",\"role\":\"admin\"}}","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"responseType":"json","xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"host":"4wdmydkl7e.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com","path":"/test/addUser"}}`

---- Upate 1 -----

I have added the following to my polyfills.js,

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

and this to my index.html

```
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did an amplify delete i.e. removed the amplify from my angular 2 project and moved to the nodejs aws sdk, in my serverless backend code along with the existing lambda functions now I have got a few more lambdas to create , delete , and list users using the following Admin Queries API,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AddCustomAttributes.html

The documentation of Amplify is still broken and therefore, I will recommend to go for a much robust API / SDK as mentioned in the link above.